# How to properly convert an objects array to a CSV file with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I need to perform a mongo query and convert results to CSV file. I've came across with `node-csv` but I can't figure out how to pass the query results to this module to convert it and actually generate a file.

So I've read this (adapting my code a bit to fit my query example):

```
var generate = require('csv-generate');

var generator = generate({objectMode: true, headers: 7});

var columns = {
  _id: '_id',
  first_name: 'first_name',
  last_name: 'last_name',
  team: 'team.name',
  position: 'position',
  status: 'status'
};
var stringifier = stringify({ header: true, columns: columns });

generator.pipe(stringifier).pipe(process.stdout);
```

And I do queries like:

```
Player.find({},{_id: true, first_name: true, last_name: true, "team.name": true, position: true, status:true}).exec(function (err,players){
  // Should CONVERT to CSV string AND generate file HERE
});
```

However I really can't figure out what steps I should follow in order to generate a CSV string and convert it to file from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way (which is also memory friendly) is to use streams. First, you do the MongoDB request:

```
collection.find({ some: "thing" }, function (err, cursor) {
    if (err) { return ...; }
    function next () {
      cursor.nextObject(function (err, obj) {
         if (err) { return ...; }
         if (obj === null) {
              return outputStream.end();
         }
         outputStream.write(stringify(obj));
         next();
      });
    }
    next();
});
```

...the `outputStream` could be an HTTP response stream (supposing you are inside of a http server request - response) or any other writable stream.

This is more or less just the basic example -- probably it could be improved, but that's how I recommend it: stringify objects one by one and write them in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

With mongoose, you can get a readable stream with `stream()` method. Then just pipe this with csv transform stream:

```
  var stringifier = csv.stringify({ header: true, columns: columns });
  Player.find()
  .stream()
  .pipe(csv.transform(function(record){
    record = record.toObject() //convert mongoose document to JS object
    return Object.keys(record).map(function(key){return record[key]}) // return array of columns
  }))
  .pipe(stringifier)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply return the js object from the handler function in "csv.transform". "csv.stringify" will accept objects when the columns options is provided.

Comment: Could you extend more in your answer?